# awk script to eliminate special characters

Tags: awk

My output looks like below

```
judi# *diff -C 0 $* mountYday mountTday
*** mountYday   Sat Jun 13 02:57:09 2015
--- mountTday   Sat Jun 13 02:59:49 2015
***************
*** 20 ****
- /test on /dev/vx/dsk/test/test read/write/setuid/devices/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=48986a5 on Wed Apr 22 22:28:04 2015
--- 19 ----
judi#
```

I need to get only the line starts with single "-".
The output should be as

```
- /test on /dev/vx/dsk/test/test read/write/setuid/devices/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=48986a5 on Wed Apr 22 22:28:04 2015
```

I am able to eliminate the first two lines using awk:

```
*# diff -C 0 $* mountYday mountTday | awk '! /mount/'*

***************
*** 20 ****
- /ora03/oradata1 on /dev/vx/dsk/GRPA056L/ora03-oradata1 read/write/setuid/devices/intr/largefiles/logging/xattr/onerror=panic/dev=48986a5 on Wed Apr 22 22:28:04 2015
--- 19 ----
```

How do I remove the lines starts with `***` and `---` (exactly 3 `***` and `---`) and the `***************` (15 Characters)? I am trying with awk in single command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of removing characters you don't want, how about a command to find the character you do want?  The line you want is "start of line, followed by a single -, followed by space".

```
$  diff -C 0 $* mountYday mountTday | awk /- / {print $0}
```

This sort of pattern extraction is more suited to grep:

```
$  diff -C 0 $* mountYday mountTday | grep '^- '
```

Comment: Thanks ... This one works #diff -C 0 $* mountYday mountTday | grep '^- '     .. I missed to notice the space after the - ... Thanks a lot Rob